# Changing Button position to top when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout with about 20 buttons. I want to be able to change the button's position to the top of the screen when clicked. for example. the user clicks button # 7 i want the layout to scroll automatically so button #7 is on the top position of the screen.
please help out with some code

Thanks for Viewing

Comment: Could you put them in an ArrayList and display them that way and then change the position with the index? Maybe create a function that is called from onClick that moves each button down and puts the clicked button at index 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`

Grab a reference to your `ScrollView` then in the `onClick` of the buttons use
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo(int, int)
to scroll to the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your goal as JBirdVegas said or you can do one quick thing is. . .

1. Make ListView with Button on every index
2. Now onItemClickListener of the listview put below code and pass pressed index.

   setSelection(index)

e.g.

```
you can use `setSelection(index)` so the display will jump to the index you want
```

Hope you will get the point.

Enjoy Coding. :)